# How to stop my 2-year-old son from stealing his sister's bottle?

Tags: toddler

He is 2 years and 2 months, she is 5 months old. He keeps stealing her milk bottle every time we blink. We got him the same pink bottle but it did not work. I even tried giving him formula milk that his sister drinks even when he drinks cow milk. Both solutions were a failure.

I have made both of them a bottle at the same time, he puts his on the table and goes straight to steal hers.

Comment: It sounds a bit like he's looking for attention, rather than her particular bottle or drink. What does he do if you give her a bottle, let him take it, then give her a second one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's time for him to learn that he doesn't get to take things away from other people just because he feels like it (for whatever reason). Though she probably doesn't *feel* disrespected when her bottle is taken away from her yet, eventually she will feel this way and more if his behavior is allowed to continue.

To some degree, has been supplanted in his parents' attentions by this little upstart. Of course, he wants what she has - both her bottle and her parents' attention. Having a new baby in the family may be one of the toughest things your older child has to deal with. Often two-year-olds have more trouble getting used to a new baby because their needs for time and closeness from their parents are still great.

Let him know taking her food away from her is *not* ok. This will help with other behaviors which are not ok: hurting her, taking her toys, etc.

Do let him know you love him just as much and he's still just as special to you as he was before.  Spend some one-on-one with him every day. Let your son choose the activity, and follow his lead.

Listen to how your child feels about the baby and the changes in your family.  If they express negative feelings, acknowledge them.  Help your child put their feelings into words (teach him feeling words).  Never deny or discount your child’s feelings.

There is a tendency to suddenly (but without intending to) expect your child to become more independent when you have a new baby.  If you expect *less* independence, you are more likely to get more, so it's ok to baby him to some extent (hold him more often, carry him as much or more than before, etc.) for a while.

Remind visitors to pay attention to your older child, and not just the baby.

Make sure the older child has some special, private space, and things of their own that they don’t have to share with the baby. The baby likewise should have things she does not need to share (like her bottle.)

Let them participate in the baby’s care—baths, dressing, pushing the stroller, etc. if he wants to, and does it gently.

Point out the benefits of being an older child, like choosing what to eat, being able to go the park and play, and having friends.

Some of these ideas and more (what books you can read to your child, etc.) can be found below.

[New Baby Sibling: Helping Your Older Child (or Children) Adjust](http://www.med.umich.edu/yourchild/topics/newbaby.htm)
[Helping your preschooler adjust to a new sibling](http://www.babycenter.com/0_helping-your-preschooler-adjust-to-a-new-sibling_3636582.bc)
[Helping Your Older Child Adjust to the New Baby](http://www.ahaparenting.com/ages-stages/newborns/Help-Sibling-Child-Adjust-New-Baby)
[New sibling: Preparing your older child - Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-living/childrens-health/in-depth/new-sibling/art-20044270)

Comment: +1 Talk to them and listen to them in return, i.e. treat them like you would any other human. Just because you don't "think" they can understand doesn't mean they don't, it just takes a bit more time sometimes.